# How can I get datagrid cell value in runtime (C# WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid linked to a database through Data Binding with Entity Framework. It has 3 columns and when the application is running the user can add new rows directly in the datagrid. Following the xaml code:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridIMP" Height="115" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
  GridLinesVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CellEditEnding="dataGridIMP_CellEditEnding">
<DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Importação" x:Name="colunaImp" DisplayMemberPath="Ref"
            SelectedValuePath="OID" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=OIDImportacao}" />
     <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Finalidade Pag" x:Name="colunaFinalidade" DisplayMemberPath="Nome"
            SelectedValuePath="OID" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=OIDTipoPagamento}"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=ValorPorImportacao, Converter={StaticResource ConvDolarTexto}}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

In runtime, after the user chooses the data from the comboboxes of the datagrid's first two columns (DataGridComboBoxColumns), the application should get these information from the cells (columns), perform some bacground query/calculation and fill the third column with some suggested value.

I have already tried to do that by getting the object entity value:

```
var rel = dataGridIMP.SelectedItem as RelacaoImpCboFIN;
int val1 = rel.OIDImportacao                //get the first column value (using entity object)
int val2 = rel.OIDTipoPagamento             //get the second column value (using entity object)

rel.ValorPorImportacao = somevalue          //set the third column value (using entity object)
```

But the data will only be assigned to the entity object after the user goes to the next row. Does anyone know how can I get the datagrid columns(cells) values just after the user edit each cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try CellEditEnding event? The eventargs has an 'EditingElement' property which will give you the actual editing element (ComboBox in this case), you can use it to find the 'SelectedValue' in the cell.

Comment: Hi AjS, your solution works fine to get the value of the cell being edited. Is there one way to get the value from another cell from the same row at the same time?

Comment: I believe 'e.Row.DataContext' returns the actual bound object to the row. You can use that to access all the required properties.